# 3 by 3 grid with image button in each cell on Android

Tags: android, layout, runtime, tablerow

I want to have a grid with 3 columns and 3 rows and an image button in each cell (center of cell).

I tried with gridview but I can't fix the number of rows.
I tried with a tablelayout and 3 tablerows, but I can't change width/height at runtime

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a tablelayout you just need to do the following on each ImageButton:

```
this.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
this.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
```